# Wordpress not adding -2 to slugs when saving post as draft

Tags: slug

I have a client that saves pretty much everything as draft before posting it on the website.

Thing is, he has a 'Jobs' section, where the name of the job offers might repeat. If they are looking for Technicians in two locations ate the same time for instance, they will create 2 posts called 'Technician' and taxonomies will differentiate between the both of them.

The problem is that by saving the post as a draft first, and then publishing it, the slug created doesn't seem to care if that slug is already taken. For example, both 'Technician' posts will have the slug '/technician/' and not '/technician/' and '/technician-2/'.

Is there any way to make Wordpress check for slug availability before assigning the slug to the post when they save it as draft?

PS: I know I can modify the slug manually, but the client doesn't want to bother.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran a quick test and there shouldn't necessarily be a "slug" -- `post_name` in the `$wpdb->posts` table-- until the post is published, so something is going wrong with your site-- something has been modified.

WordPress already checks for duplicate slugs. This is pretty critical functionality as certain permalink structures depend upon it. The function used is [`wp_unique_post_slug()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_unique_post_slug). [You can see it used in `wp_insert_post()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/post.php#L3325)